# Anyone manage to deploy a WSP without it forcing an IISReset?

Tags: solution-package, iis

I'm working in SharePoint 2010 and have been unable to deploy (or retract) my WSP without causing an IISReset.  Here's my situation:

- The solution contains:

  - Fields
  - One content type
  - A page layout based on the content type
  - A bunch of images that go into the style library
- There is ZERO code in the solution
- I've manually edited the manifest.xml

  - Removed the assembly, so nothing would get deployed to the GAC
  - Set ResetWebServer="False" in the Solution tag

Still, every retract or deploy takes down ALL web applications on the server.  Is there any way even to restrict it just to one web app?  Thanks!

Comment: You say you removed the assembly, yet you say there's zero code in the solution? What assembly did you generate in order to be added to the package?

Comment: In VS2010, even if you start with a blank SharePoint solution, it generates a dll for the project and you get a reference to it in the manifest.xml.  Since I haven't added any code to the solution, I assume that dll is "empty", for lack of a better word.  I removed the assembly reference in the manifest.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Visual Studio's Deploy function?

If you did, this could be why, as it does a full retract/deploy with reset and the works.

if you want a more granular approach just use the Package function and deploy/retract manually using PowerShell (or stsadm if you are totally retro;-)

Comment: Good question.  I'm packaging up the WSP and using powershell commands to deploy.  But it does the same thing even if I deploy through Central Admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a sandbox solution and setting the "Include Assembly in Package" property to false to avoid deploying a .dll.

Try [this post](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=71)

Comment: "Include Assembly in Package" has no effect on whether IIS resets, I have found.  :(  And I can't use a sandbox solution for my case.